# Custom template for category WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello I'm new in WordPress custom templates. Can anybody tell me how I can load a different template for a category.

Here is the index.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * No comment for now
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage site
 * @since site
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
    $strFr='Featured';
    $strFinancial='Financial Reports';
    $strResearch='Research';
?>

    <div id="page-body" role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 SearchTop">
                    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" class="form-control customsearchfiled" placeholder="Search of anything related to Site" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- SearchTop -->

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb20 no-gutter">

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-gutter">
                        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php else : ?>

                            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">

                                <?php if (current_user_can('edit_posts')) :
                                    // Show a different message to a logged-in user who can add posts.
                                    ?>
                                    <header class="entry-header">
                                        <h1 class="entry-title mt20"><?php _e('No posts to display', 'twentytwelve'); ?></h1>
                                    </header>

                                    <!--<div class="entry-content">
                                        <p><?php //printf(__('Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%s">Get started here</a>.', 'twentytwelve'), admin_url('post-new.php')); ?></p>
                                    </div> .entry-content -->

                                <?php else :
                                    // Show the default message to everyone else.
                                    ?>
                                    <header class="entry-header">
                                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e('Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve'); ?></h1>
                                    </header>

                                    <div class="entry-content">
                                        <p><?php _e('Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve'); ?></p>
                                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                                <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>

                            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

                        <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As far I know the index file is calling content php file that shows the post layout but don't know how to do this. Tried a lot of things but only get php error. I don't know php syntax much

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom template with better structure than WP default.
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage site
 * @since Site 1.0
 */

# for one post
if (is_single()) {
    ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php if(function_exists('pf_show_link')){echo pf_show_link();} ?>
            <p class="text-center topcategory">
                <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
                    echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
                    }
                ?>
            </p>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <p class="postmetadown">By :<span class="bluecolor"><?php the_author(); ?></span> | <span><?php the_date() ?></span></p>
        </header>

        <div class="entry-content col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <?php the_content(__('Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve')); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __('Pages:', 'twentytwelve'), 'after' => '</div>')); ?>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div>

        <?php if (comments_open()) : ?>
            <!--<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
            ￼￼￼￼
            <script type="text/javascript">
                /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
                var disqus_shortname = 'site'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

                /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
                (function () {
                    var dsq = document.createElement('script');
                    dsq.type =
                        'text/javascript';
                    dsq.async = true;
                    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||
                        document.getElementsByTagName('body')
                            [0]).appendChild(dsq);
                })();
            </script>
            <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/? ref_noscript">comments powered
                    by Disqus.</a></noscript>
            <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq- brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo- disqus">Disqus</span></a>-->
        <?php endif; ?>
        <footer class="entry-meta col-md-12">
            <?php if ($googlePlusAcc = get_the_author_meta('googleplus')) { ?>
                <?php hr_single_entry_meta(); ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'twentytwelve'), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>'); ?>
            <?php if (is_singular() && get_the_author_meta('description') && is_multi_author()) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
                <div class="author-info">
                    <div class="author-avatar">
                        <?php
                        /** This filter is documented in author.php */
                        $author_bio_avatar_size = apply_filters('twentytwelve_author_bio_avatar_size', 68);
                        echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $author_bio_avatar_size);
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .author-avatar -->
                    <div class="author-description">
                        <h2><?php printf(__('About %s', 'twentytwelve'), get_the_author()); ?></h2>

                        <p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>

                        <div class="author-link">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'))); ?>"
                               rel="author">
                                <?php printf(__('View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve'), get_the_author()); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </footer>
    </article>
<?php
#for listing page
} else {

    $category = get_the_category();
    if (!empty($category))
        $category = $category[0];
    ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php //if (is_sticky() && is_home() && !is_paged()) : ?>
            <!--<div class="featured-post">
                <?php //_e('Featured post', 'twentytwelve'); ?>
            </div>-->
        <?php //endif; ?>       

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 categoryimg no-gutter">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                <div class="post-thumbnal-wrapper-multiple">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 categoryContent">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h1>
            </header>

            <?php if (is_search()) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
                <div class="entry-summary">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_excerpt_more(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <footer class="entry-meta">
                    <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
                    <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'twentytwelve'), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>'); ?>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div><!-- categoryContent -->
    </article>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a template for the category page, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates. If you want a different template for the content, based on the category, you could use (in your content.php)

```
<?php if (is_category('Category A')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category A</p>
<?php elseif (is_category('Category B')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category B</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages, 
I could be left blank</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If there's a lot of difference between categories, I would place this in index.php, and create different templates for every category

Comment: I have tried to do just like that but got php error. Don't know where's the issue. can you please add above code in my index.php or content.php file

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page [Template Hierachy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). Basically if you want to target a specific category you create a file like so `category-{slug}.php` {slug} being the category slug you want to target.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read about Wordpress Template Hierarchy in https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

To answer your question, you need to create a category-{id}.php or category-{slug}.php file. in your theme folder (Choose only one)

- id = your category ID
- slug = your category slug

After creating the file, then you can put your custom code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add your code inside archive.php which will list all the posts in the category and add the detail page template inside single.php .

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates